# Run a local html file as http:// and not file://

Tags: file, http, localhost, textures, webgl

I try to use `webgl` examples, where there are textures (images and video), so i downloaded examples from internet, but the problem is that i cant use them directly from the browser, because the protocole `file://` will be used and not `http://` and that block the texture and make an error from javascript console:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

So, how do i use ONLY a browser to mimic the internet `HTTP` protocol?

Comment: Install a web server if you need http, but i think that this will not fix the error

Comment: with a local server, it worked, but i needed a way to use only browsers

Comment: There is no way to make a web browser act as a web server. You need a real web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on a system with Python (e.g. available by default on OS X) switch to the folder you want to serve and use:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]
```

Then use a browser to open `http://localhost:[port]`

Comment: thank you! that worked! but, the browser cant emulate a server to convert the file to http?

Comment: the files of your folder are served using HTTP. In case you want to test plain html or js this is a viable setup. For PHP or any other interpreted languages you need a different setup (e.g. Apache).

Comment: i will go with tornado then (i am only from python world)

Comment: There is no way to make a web browser act as a web server. You need a real web server, which is what `SimpleHTTPServer` provides.